# How can I add a delay inside each iteration of an _.each loop in underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, loops, underscore.js

How can I add a delay inside each iteration of an _.each loop to space out the calling of an interior function by 1 second?

```
  _.each(this.rows, function (row, i) {
      row.setChars(msg[i] ? msg[i] : ' ');
  });
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit?

Comment: Essentially, I was looking to space out calling of row.setChars by 1 second per row.

Comment: Your solution is redundant

Comment: Which part is redundant?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need extra IIFE

```
_.each(this.rows, function (row, i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        row.setChars(msg[i] ? msg[i] : ' ');
    }, 1000 * i);
});
```

since you're not doing it in an explicit `for` loop.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, this is a better answer than my solution.

Comment: if the answer is acceptable, you should consider accepting it.

Comment: I know this is a bit late to the party, but this just saved my a**... if anyone is wondering why this works - when looping with _.each, the timers are all being set almost immediately on all of the objects at once. So at the interval mark (1 second, in this case), all of the timers are expiring. So this is a really creative solution :)

Comment: Great answer, very clever approach

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, just add a self invoking function inside the _.each loop with a timeout that continues to scale based on the number of iterations of the loop.

Here's a working example (Edited to remove redundancy):

```
  _.each(this.rows, function (row, i) {
      setTimeout(function () {
          row.setChars(msg[i] ? msg[i] : ' ');
      }, 1000 * i);
  });
```

Comment: Whats the difference between your and @zerkms answer?

Comment: My answer came first and I edited to remove redundancy so as not to confuse anyone