# Add pause inside loop that transforms array? [was: inside Underscore.js _.each loop]

Tags: javascript

How can I set a delay inside an Underscore.js `_.each` loop that transforms an array? This is my current code:

```
    _.each(boundaries.features, function(feature, i) {
        feature = _this.getBoundary(feature, values, activeNames);
    });
```

Now I want to add a pause every thousandth loop, so that the script doesn't lock up IE8.

First attempt:

```
    _.each(boundaries.features, function(feature, i) {
        feature = _this.getBoundary(feature, values, activeNames);
        // Stop IE locking up.
        if (i % 1000 === 0) {
            function assign() {
               feature = _this.getBoundary(feature, values, activeNames);
            }
            window.setTimeout(assign, 20);
        }
    });
```

Pretty sure this isn't going to work though.

UPDATE: Second attempt, with condition added for IE8 only. Does this look vaguely sensible?

```
   var newData = [];
   function iterateOverItems(items, startItem) {
     for (i = startItem; i < items.length; i++) {
       newData.push(transformItem(items[i]));
       if ((i % 1000 === 0) && (!document.addEventListener)) {
            window.setTimeout(iterateOverItems, 100);
            break;
       }
   }
   iterateOverItems(items, 0);
```

Ugh, that's not going to work because I can't pass the required arguments to the recursive function. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you cannot. Don't use `_.each` if you need to pause.

Comment: What should I do instead? Should I create a copy of the array?

Comment: Write a recursive function that iterates over the chunks of the array, and uses a `for` loop to iterate 1000 items in each. Then you can use `setTimeout` for the recursive call to the next chunk.

Comment: Thanks - I want to *transform* the array, not just loop over it, though... I guess I could create a new array and push things on to it, maybe...?

Comment: added a second attempt...

Comment: Looks good, although I wonder why you need this async execution in oldIE only. You'll need to rewrite your code that uses `newData` to always consider the asynchronous case anyway

Comment: You can pass the arguments to the recursive invocation by using a function expression closure: `setTimeout(function() { iterateOverItems(items, i+1); }, 10)`

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "you'll need to rewrite your code... to consider the asynchronous case" - why? Do you mean that I shouldn't start working with `newData` until I'm sure that all the timeouts have finished? In which case, how should I do that?

Comment: Also I've just found this, which might be a neater way of dealing with the `_.each` loop? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24502232/194000

Comment: Yes, exactly, you will need to wait for the timeouts before the `newData` is filled with the results, otherwise it is still empty. That code in the other question doesn't consider this, as it just schedules the timeouts for theirs side effects (not for building a result)

Comment: Thanks. I'm really struggling a bit with this. Any pointers for somewhere to look for an example? I don't think I even know what to Google for :( The overall problem should surely be quite simple? I've got a big array I want to transform, but I want to loop over it without killing IE, so I want to pause a bit every 1000 loops. Can it really be this complex in JS?